# Using @Resource for Geode region after @EnableClusterDefinedRegions

Tags: spring-boot-data-geode

My spring boot data geode `@Controller` endpoint sets up an rsocket response which `@Autowired` a service class from another package:

```
@Controller
public class RSocketController {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RSocketController.class);

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
```

The `myService` class contains `@Resource` regions which were setup by `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` from a Geode cluster.

```
@Resource
private Region<String, Request> request;
```

When an rsocket request is sent to the endpoint the `@Autowired` service gives an error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'request' available`

I have some domain objects decorated with `@Region` that I also decorated with `@Controller` and `@Configuration` and these gave errors like:

```
Bean named 'request' is expected to be of type 'org.apache.geode.cache.Region' but was actually of type 'region.request'
```

and

```
Bean named 'request' is expected to be of type org.apache.geode.cache.Region but was actually of type region.request$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e6b7dd1
```

When I turned on debug logs I see that the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` has somehow not triggered and therefore not setup the `request` region from the Geode cluster. Aaargh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved by adding `@Component` annotation to the `@EnableClusterDefinedRegions` class which was then seen by Spring Boot bean collector.